# How do I use JQ to select a handful of objects matching an ID in a large json file?

Tags: jq

Say I have a large file of JSON lines (more than 10k) like so:

```
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "12345"}}}
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "23456"}}}
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "33445"}}}
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "24656"}}}
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "15523"}}}
{"type": "RECORD", "record": {"stream": "...", "data": {"ticketNumber": "30030"}}}
```

I am trying to use `jq` to extract only the records whose ticketNumbers are "24656" and "33445". I've tried the following command

```
cat datafile.json | jq '.record.data | select(.ticketNumber | map(in(["24656", "33445"])))'
```

What have I done wrong here?

But all I get are errors saying "error at .... cannot iterate over string ('...')").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you check the ticker number is present in the allowed list, is not quite right, the `map(..)` and `in` are not correctly used. You can do something like

```
["24656", "33445"] as $valid | select(.record.data.ticketNumber | IN($valid[]))
```

[jqplay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2mDXlp_RfQf)

Comment: Is there an advantage to define the `$valid`? Why not just `| IN(["24656", "33445"][])`

Comment: Left to the user to customize as they wish. Basically separate out the config out of the actual logic. They can decide to pass it as an `--argjson` or use it as my answer. I don't like hardcoding stuff inside the functional part